# 64 bit guest on a 32 bit host

Tags: ubuntu, qemu

I've been searching around here but didn't found a proper answer.

I have problems to start a 64bit (ubuntu-amd64) guest system on a 32bit ubuntu host, using qemu.

I've made sure that the kvm kernel modules are available:

```
lsmod | grep kvm
kvm
kvm_amd
```

Also I've made sure, that my CPU supports hardware virtualization:

```
grep svm /proc/cpuinfo
... svm ....
```

I try to start the vm using the following command. I've simplified it for this test in a way that it has only a CDROM drive:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -cdrom ubuntu-12.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso
```

After the bootsplash of ubuntu has been shown I got the error message:

> This kernel requires an x86-64 CPU, but only detected an i686 CPU
>   Unable to boot - please use a kernel appropriate for your CPU

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: maybe [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/56124/can-i-run-a-64-bit-vmware-image-on-a-32-bit-machine) are some useful answers.

Comment: @Gizmo Thx for the link. It was helpful but I'm still unable to run the machine. Have done all that steps in the qemu tutorials. As far as I understood them the cmd above should just work. Maybe my system lacks of a fundamental feature.

Comment: you need to run without the -KVM switch, add -no-kvm, it should work but it's so slow it's a pain. Also what CPU do you have? Maybe I can look further into details if that won't work. Try also specifying the CPU with the -cpu switch.

Comment: @Gizmo Yes, now it starts to boot but it's sooooooooooo slow. All the (guest) kernel says is 'soft lockup' :) Host CPU calls itself `AMD Athlon(tm) Neo X2 Dual Core Processor L325`

Comment: well, unless you run a 64bit kernel, -no-kvm is the only option. I'll add this as an answer.

Comment: @Gizmo the guest finished with a kernel panic. This seems not to work.

Comment: Like I said, it's slow and -no-kvm is a pain :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to run without the -KVM switch, add -no-kvm, it should work but it's so slow it's a pain. unless you run a 64bit kernel, -no-kvm is the only option to run a 64bit guest on a 32bit kernel.

I don't know a (100% working) qemu solution but I know [VirtualBox](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/15788) and VMWare can do it.

Comment: Where do you have this information from? The qemu manuals doesn't say so

Comment: [source](https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-866381-start-0.html)

Comment: Nice, in that article they say that it is working with virtualbox. And yes, with virtualbox it is working. Didn't had expected this. %)

Comment: Will wait a little bit unless I mark the answer as accepted because I still hope to get some more input regarding a qemu solution.. But many thx for your help!

Comment: maybe I don't know a qemu solution but I know [VirtualBox](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/15788) and VMWare can do it.

Comment: I would add the last sentence to your answer. Virtualbox is ok as a workaround for desktop virtualization (I currently need that)

Comment: alright done :)